# Management of branching on Subversion

Tags: svn, branch

We need to make a `branch` on **Subverison** in these days on our project.

One time `branch` made, we need to manage in practise 2 projects contemporary. This means, that if we resolve a bug on the `branch` we should make it also on `trunk`. First times it would basically easy merging, but more time pass, more `trunk` will defer from `branch`, so will be need to make specific fixes to resolve a problem on trunk and on branch.

The problem:

To ensure that none forgets to bring the fix from `branch` to `trunk`, I was thinking to write simple program that checks commits on `branch`, reads a comments and try to find *exactly the same* comments on `trunk`.  Roughe one.

Is there any more clever solution for this ?

Comment: What purpose do you follow with the branch you've created?

Comment: @khmbarbaise: it's a program release. So we separate oficial release from dev one.

Comment: So the usual workflow of such an approach (release branching) is to merge back everything from the branch, which usually contains only bug fixes for stabelizing  the release, back to the trunk. What also could be done to merge back changes from the branch on a scheduled based if the branch is a long living candidate...

Comment: "scheduled based merge" I think is written on top of Inferno Gates :) Hate it, after a while you lose more time to fix conflicts then if you did it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only sane approach is to have automated tests, and fail the build if a test fails. You should perhaps manage the tests outside the trunk/branch distinction, or maybe keep all of the test suite on the trunk, and set up each test case so that it is run in the appropriate branch(es) too.

```
case $1 in trunk | 2.13branch ) run this test ;; esac
```

... or probably more like, only skip the test for certain named old legacy branches for which the fix is not supposed to be available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use svn externals to to ensure the code is identical when it should be and re-build daily: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html

Comment: The code can not be "identical". It for sure will be different, as we are talking about branch and trunk. I want to be sure that a bugfix made on branch ported to trunk. It's not necessary the same lines of code.

Comment: In my **personal** opinion you're building it incorrectly then. There must obviously be branch specific things but if you've got functions etc buried in code that are the same when the code around it isn't then the functions should be saved separately and used where necessary so any bug-fixes are ported between branch and trunk. If your code is so different then there's almost no point in branching it.

Comment: it's not "so" different, but it can be different. Even a bug that happens on branch can be not reproducable on trunk, or reproducable in completely different way. This is not NOW. But will for sure happen in a year. So I want to be prepared and have a solution to verify if the fix actually was made. I can not say that, if the same lines, same files or even same functions are checked means that fix is made. For NOW it would work, may be, after a year instead, will not for sure.